# Python regex: find only the variable value matching '.+'

Tags: python, regex

I wrote the following program to calculate the marks. Is their a better way of finding only the marks.

```
import re

string = """
Q1
|-->1
|-->1
|-->1
|-->1
|-->1
"""
pattern = '>.+\n'

result = re.findall(pattern, string)
marks = 0
for x in result:
    marks += int(x.replace('>', '').replace('\n', ''))
#This thing does not look clean; it feels hacky
print(marks)
```

The re.findall() returns list something like this

```
['>1\n', '>1\n', ...]
```

But I want somrthing like this

```
['1', '1', ...]
```

What should I do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regex find all approach here:

```py
string = """
Q1
|-->1
|-->1
|-->1
|-->1
|-->1
"""

grades = re.findall(r'-->(\d+)', string)
print(grades)  # ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```